# IIF Microsoft Access Statement Error Help - Multiple IIF Statements in one query

Tags: sql, ms-access, iif

hoping someone can help me.

I'm trying to run this query, but i get the below error. I need to build logic, based on different fields in different tables then write that data to a new field in a table. This is just the start of my query but i'm already getting error :/

The logic I am trying to write is

> if Containersize = '20' and CBMRate*PLX < 20MRate then use CBMRate*PLX
> else use 20MRate if Containersize = '40' and CBMRate*PLX < 40MRate
> then use CBMRate*PLX else use 40MRate if Containersize = 'LCL' and
> CBMRate*PLX < LCLMRate the use CBMRate*PLX else LCLMRate

Here is the query I wrote but I have something with the syntax wrong. Any help would be appreciated. :)

```
Select IIF ([Shipments]![ContainerSize] = '20') ,
(IIF (([CustomerRates]![CBMRate] * [Shipments]![PLX]) < [CustomerRates]![20MRate]) , ([CustomerRates]![CBMRate] * [Shipments]![PLX]) , ([CustomerRates]![20MRate])) , (IIF 
([Shipments]![ContainerSize] = '40') ,
(IIF ([CustomerRates]![CBMRate] * [Shipments]![PLX]) < [CustomerRates]![40MRate]), ([CustomerRates]![CBMRate] * [Shipments]![PLX]) , ([CustomerRates]![40MRate])),
(IIF  ([CustomerRates]![CBMRate] * [Shipments]![PLX]) < [CustomerRates]![LCLMRate]), ([CustomerRates]![CBMRate] * [Shipments]![PLX]) , ([CustomerRates]![LCLMRate]))
From [CustomerRates] , [Shipments]
Where
[shipments]![customerid]=[customerRates]![customerid]
```

Comment: I think there is too many brackets. For example on first line before comma the `IIF` statement is closed. And I think there is a similar problem with the other `IIF`s.

Comment: You should just remove all the redundant brackets. There should be one at the start and one at the end of each `IFF` like so `IIF(condition, IIF(condition, true, false), IIF(condition, IIF(condition, true, false), IIF(condition, true, false)))`

Answer (score 1):

If fields are number type, don't use text delimiters.
 
Consider:

```
IIf([ContainerSize] = 20, IIf([CBMRate] * [PLX] < [20MRate], [CBMRate] * [PLX], [20MRate]), 
    IIf([ContainerSize] = 40, IIf([CBMRate] * [PLX] < [40MRate], [CBMRate] * [PLX], [40MRate]),
        IIf([CBMRate] * [PLX] < [LCLMRate]), [CBMRate] * [PLX], [LCLMRate])))
```

Or

```
Switch([ContainerSize] = 20, IIf([CBMRate] * [PLX] < [20MRate], [CBMRate] * [PLX], [20MRate]),
       [ContainerSize] = 40, IIf([CBMRate] * [PLX] < [40MRate], [CBMRate] * [PLX], [40MRate]),
       True, IIf([CBMRate] * [PLX] < [LCLMRate]), [CBMRate] * [PLX], [LCLMRate]))
```